# Changing colour of the other svg element in a group

Tags: css, svg, hover

I'm trying to use css to change the colour of an element of an svg when it is hovered over, but also to change the colour of the same element when the other element of the group is hovered over.

The code for the svg group is:

```
<g id="Locations">
        <g id="Viner_Gallery">
            <path id="vinerGalleryQ" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-    miterlimit="10" d="M281.199,341.615c0,0-1.607,0-16.165,0
                c-8.927,0-16.165-7.237-16.165-16.165c0-8.928,7.237-16.165,16.165-16.165c8.928,0,16.165,7.237,16.165,16.165
                c0,3.792-1.306,7.278-3.492,10.036L281.199,341.615z"/>
            <polygon id="vinerGalleryPoly" fill="#4D4D4D" points="264.973,315.891 255.245,332.141 274.495,332.141       "/>
        </g>
</g>
```

I want to change the colour of #vinerGalleryQ when hovered over, but I also want to change the colour of #vinerGalleryQ when #vinerGalleryPoly is hovered over.

I've tried jQuery, which I would prefer to css but I can't make that work at all - apparently there are some problems with jQuery and svg?

Comment: Not possible with CSS as there is no previous sibling selector. Jquery should be possible....you just need to do some more research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```css
.rect1 {
  fill: red;
}

.rect2 {
  fill: green;
}

g:hover .rect1 {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect class="rect1" width="140" height="150"/>
    <rect class="rect2" x="150" width="140" height="150"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```